# pymysql: 2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on %r (%s)" % (self.host, e))

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

Using Python-2.7.6 and package "pymysql" and "MySQL-python" are installed using "easy_install-2.7"
From python script I am trying to make a connection to remote MySQL server (both client and mysql server are in same subnet)

Script:

```
cluster_inbound_ip="10.0.xx.xx"
conn = pymysql.connect(host=cluster_inbound_ip, port=cluster_port, user=db_root_user, passwd=db_root_pass, db = db_name)
```

Error after compiling script

```
  File "/root/test_case.py", line 41, in setup_module
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=cluster_inbound_ip, port=cluster_port, user=db_root_user, passwd=db_root_pass, db = db_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/pymysql/__init__.py", line 88, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/pymysql/connections.py", line 634, in __init__
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyMySQL-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/pymysql/connections.py", line 818, in _connect
    2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on %r (%s)" % (self.host, e))
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.xx.xx' (%d format: a number is required, not str)")
```

I am able ping as well as able to connect to MySQL server from command line from my client.
Also, I verified adding MySQL and HTTP ports in the iptables service as suggested by "[Olaf Erlandsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901197/olaf-erlandsen)" for similar [MySQLdb Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824352/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-s-mysqldb)

Can anyone suggest or help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is `10.0.xx.xx` the actual IP you are using?

Comment: Are you passing the port as a string or an int?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco No, I am using actual IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that the error actually comes from this line:

```
self.host_info = "socket %s:%d" % (self.host, self.port)
```

If you are passing in port as a str instead of as an int, then this is what you would expect.

For example:

```
>>> print "socket %s:%d" % ("localhost", 8000)
socket localhost:8000
>>> print "socket %s:%d" % ("localhost", '8000')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: yes, that's true! it was actually throwing an error due to port. Thanks a lot, it would have taken ages to figure out for me :)